# How to loop a sliding <div> from right to left with multiple images in it

Tags: html, css

I try to create a gallery in the background that can keep sliding (looping) from left to right, which means when the last image of the gallery appears, the next one will be the first column of the gallery

like this:
[image]

but right now the gallery won't loop, after the last one appears, it will only follow by blank space, and then it will suddenly shift back to where it started.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sliding-background">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="img-hover-zoom">
                        <img src="img/1.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-hover-zoom">
                        <img src="img/2.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-hover-zoom">
                        <img src="img/3.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <div class="img-hover-zoom">
                        <img src="img/4.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-hover-zoom">
                        <img src="img/5.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-hover-zoom">
                        <img src="img/6.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column{
    flex: 25%;

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.sliding-background {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    position: absolute;
}

@keyframes slide{
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-201%);
      }
  }
```

Comment: You can not just make an HTML element "wrap around", so that the end of it shows on the left side of the screen, and then the start of it comes in on the other side again ... Almost all slider implementations you will find out there, _clone_ a certain number of the slide elements, so that those can be shown "at the end", before the whole slider resets to its initial position again.